# Angular 7: JWT expiration time check error

Tags: angular, jwt, angular7

I'm create an angular application. Currently i'm wants to check JWT expiration time. I'm wants to check JWT exp time before every API call.
Ex:

1. https://example.com/get-user-details (Exp time over, then call refresh token API)
2. https://example.com/refresh-token (get a vnew valid JWT token, store in local storage & **complete 1st API call - https://example.com/get-user-details**)

But i'm getting an error.

> Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: You provided 'undefined' where a
> stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or
> Iterable.

I'm thinking their is an error on async/await function, but i'm not able to solve this issue.

```
import {Inject, Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {
    HttpClient,
    HttpErrorResponse,
    HttpEvent,
    HttpHandler,
    HttpInterceptor,
    HttpRequest,
    HttpResponse
} from '@angular/common/http';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs';
import {catchError, tap} from 'rxjs/operators';
import {SHttpConfig} from './http.conf';
import {StorageService} from '../../services/storage.service';
import {PopAlertService} from '../pop-alert/pop-alert.service';
import {Router} from '@angular/router';
import {JwtService} from '../../services/jwt.service';
import {getDecodedJWT} from '../../helpers/functions';

@Injectable()
export class SHttpInjectorService implements HttpInterceptor {
    cachedRequests: Array<HttpRequest<any>> = [];

    constructor(
        private storage: StorageService,
        private config: SHttpConfig,
        private pop: PopAlertService,
        private router: Router,
        private jwt: JwtService
    ) {
    }

    intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        const user: any = this.storage.user;
        const addToken = !req.urlWithParams.includes('token');
        const token = user ? user.token : null;
        if (token && !req.url.includes('token=') && addToken) {
            this.modify(req, user, token).then(res => {
                req = res;
                return this.handleRequest(next, req, token);
            });
        } else {
            return this.handleRequest(next, req, token);
        }
    }

    private async modify(req, user, token) {
        let user_token = user.token;
        const expireDate = getDecodedJWT(token).exp;
        if (Date.now() >= expireDate * 1000) {
            const result = await this.jwt.getRefreshedJWT().toPromise();
            user_token = result.token;
            user.token = user_token;
            this.storage.user = user;
        }
        return req.clone({
            setHeaders: {Authorization: `Bearer ${user_token}`},
            setParams: {token: user_token}
        });
    }

    private handleRequest(next, req, token) {
        return next.handle(req).pipe(tap((event: HttpEvent<any>) => {
            if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
                if (event.body.code === 401 && token) {
                    this.router.navigate(['/']).catch(err => {console.log(err); });
                    this.storage.removeData();
                    this.pop.open('Your Session has expired ');
                }
            }
        }, (err: any) => {
            if (err instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
                if (err.status === 401) {
                    this.collectFailedRequest(req);
                } else if (err.status === 0 && err.message.match('Http failure response')) {
                    this.pop.open('Couldn\'t get response from server');
                }
            } else {
                // tslint:disable-next-line:no-shadowed-variable
                this.router.navigate(['/']).catch(err => {console.log(err); });
            }
        }));
    }

    public collectFailedRequest(request): void {
        this.cachedRequests.push(request);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As the error says is expecting a stream instead of undefined, the cause of the issue is inside the if clause:

```
   if (token && !req.url.includes('token=') && addToken) {
        this.modify(req, user, token).then(res => { // <-- here
             req = res;
             return this.handleRequest(next, req, token);
        });
   }
```

The method **intercept** is expecting to return an **Observable** and when the if condition is met it doesn't return anything because you are putting the return statement inside of an async method, so the compiler puts the callback function into the callback queue and continues to the next line and since there isn't anything it returns undefined.

I'd suggest to use Observables and the RXJS operators and do something as follows:

```
intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    const user: any = this.storage.user;
    const addToken = !req.urlWithParams.includes('token');
    const token = user ? user.token : null;
    if (token && !req.url.includes('token=') && addToken) {
        return this.modify(req, next, user, token);
    } else {
        return this.handleRequest(next, req, token);
    }
}

private modify(req, next, user, token): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    let user_token = user.token;
    const expireDate = getDecodedJWT(token).exp;
    if (Date.now() >= expireDate * 1000) {
      return this.jwt.getRefreshedJWT().pipe(flatMap((result) => {
        user_token = result.token;
        user.token = user_token;
        this.storage.user = user;
        const clonedReq =  req.clone({
            setHeaders: {Authorization: `Bearer ${user_token}`},
            setParams: {token: user_token}
        });
        return this.handleRequest(next, clonedReq, token);
      }));
    }   
    return this.handleRequest(next, req, token);
}
```

Also I think it'd be better if you handle this in a different way, since with this approach you are checking if the token has expired in every request which is adding some extra delay in all the request to the server, making the request last more than it should, instead you could go with a more lazy approach and return an error from the server if the token has expired and then you can store the request, trigger the refresh token logic and finally resume the request that failed.